# I cannot select the value data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm filling in a select, with options that I create dynamically with data that I bring from my API. The problem is that when I try to select the value that is in the value option, it only brings me the value that is in the option text.

this select is on my html page and I want to fill it with the options that I create dynamically

```
    <select data-turma class="browser-default">
            
    </select>
```

This is the javascript that is in a different document

```
const criaOption=(horario, id)=>{
    const novaOptionTurma=createElement('option')
    const option=
        `
        <option value="${id}">${horario}</option>
        `
    novaOptionTurma.innerHTML=option
    return novaOptionTurma
}
const select=document.querySelector('[data-turma]')
listaTurmas()
.then(data=>{
    data.forEach(elemento=>{
        select.appendChild(criaOption(elemento.horario,elemento.id))
    })
})

const btnPegaTurma=document.querySelector('.btn_turma')
btnPegaTurma.addEventListener('click',(evento)=>{
    evento.preventDefault()
    const turma=document.querySelector('[data-turma]').value
    console.log(turma)
    localStorage.setItem('truma', turma)
})
```

I ask him to give me the id that is in the value, but he brings me the "horário" that is in the text

Comment: I not realy understand what is the problem but why you not set name for the select field and then call to the select input value?

Comment: What does `createElement` return? It looks like you're creating something like `<option><option>...</option></option>`.

Comment: I ask him to select the id in the value, but he brings me the "horario" and I need to select the id that is in the value

Comment: in console.log is showing me the text data, not the value

Comment: Is `createElement` a function that you made, or are you trying to call the `document.createElement()` function from vanilla JS? If you made it yourself, then could you edit your question to include that code?

Comment: Is that a string or a live element? If it's an element, you're overriding all the options when you do `novaOptionTurma.innerHTML=option`.

Comment: I created this function because to create the option dynamically and insert the data I'm bringing from an api

Comment: Please re-work the title to english.

Comment: createElement is returning this to me  <optoin> <option value = "1"> 22 </option> </optoin> <option value = ""> <option value = "2"> 23 </option> </option>